# ¿Cómo mantener sincronizados los cambios entre bases de datos maestro y esclavo (respaldo)?

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu

Actualmente estoy iniciando en el campo de bases de datos postgres, entonces no tengo idea de como realizar el proceso descrito a continuación:

En el equipo que llamaré Servidor tengo una base de datos llamada Sistema, donde existe la tabla "Dispositivos", cada uno de ellos tiene su id y nombre.
Adicional existe otro equipo que llamaré Esclavo, que tiene la misma base de datos pero solo contiene una parte de los dispositivos que están registrados en la primera.

Lo que necesito es que al modificar alguno de los nombres en el Servidor el mismo se modifique en el Esclavo.

La base de datos está en postgresql, uso ubuntu como S.O por defecto, pensaba utilizar python para realizar la rutina pero en realidad no sé qué herramientas del mismo utilizar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La verdad es que puedes utilizar cualquier lenguaje de programación para esta solución.

Te puedo dar 2 aproximaciones;

1. Al crear/modificar un registro de 'Servidor' inmediatamente te conectas a la base de datos remota (Esclavo) y creas/modificas el registro.
2. Utilizas la opción de [Replication](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling) de Postgres.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me iré por el lado de replication.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar Postgres Replication si necesitas tener las dos base de datos sincronizadas (Tablas identicas o replicadas).

Otra opción es usar [Foreign Data Wrapper](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/postgres-fdw.html) la cual consiste en la comunicación entre dos bases de datos. De esta forma puedes hacer inserciones en la tabla de "Dispositivos" que tienes en "Esclavo", desde la tabla "Dispositivos" que tienes en "Maestro". Entonces primer te sugiero hacer un procedimiento almacenado con la lógica que deseas hacer (Traer los cambios del maestro al esclavo).
Luego tienes dos vías de ejecutar esta actualización:

1. Si quieres mantener constantemente actualizada la tabla de Dispostivos del Esclavo, es decir por cada inserción que vea automaticamente replicada, entonces deberás construir un trigger que llame a este procedimiento almacenado. La desventaja es la performance, ya que por cada registro
2. Si no lo necesitas de la forma anterior, puedes construir un crontab que ejecute tu procedimiento almacenado cada el tiempo que tu necesites. La ventaja es que ganas rendimiento de la aplicación del servidor maestro.

Comment: Gracias amigo, intentaré instruirme más acerca de como realizar el FDW, más que todo para la creación del trigger.